# TypeError: Human.__init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python

I don't understand why my code gives such an error if I wrote everything correctly

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def showInfo(self):
        print(self.name + ', '+ str(self.age)) 
  
class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, name, age, course):
        super().__init__(self, name, age)
        self.course = course

h01 = Human('John', 19)
h01.showInfo()
s01 = Student('James', 18, 2)
s01.showInfo()
```

But I have one more example and everything works in it, although everything is written the same way. Why is that?

```
class Home():
    '''desc home'''
    def __init__(self, street, number):
        ''''''
        self.street = street
        self.number = number
        self.age = 0

    def build(self):
        '''build home'''
        print('House on street ' + self.street + ' number ' +
              str(self.number) + ' was buit.')

    def age_of_home(self, year):
        '''home age'''
        self.age = self.age + year

class ProspectHome(Home):
    '''home prosp'''
    def __init__(self, prospect, number):
        super().__init__(self, number)
        self.prospect = prospect

PrHome = ProspectHome('Street', 5)
print(PrHome.prospect)
print(PrHome.number)
```

Comment: In `super().__init__(self, name, age)` you shouldn't pass `self`. Docs link [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

Comment: instead of `super().__init__(self, name, age)` you can  use `Human.__init__(self, name, age)`

Answer (score 1):

when calling `super` you are passing `self` so it will count the object itself as arg. remove `self` from `super`

replace:

```
super().__init__(self, name, age)
```

with:

```
super().__init__(name, age)
```

and if you want use self in super, you need to use like this:

```
super(ProspectHome, self).__init__(name, age)
```

check [this](https://realpython.com/python-super/) link to know more about `super()`

Comment: I wrote two identical examples, one of them works and the other one doesn't. Why?

Comment: beacuse  the code ```super().__init__(self, number)```,you  put two args.the "street" arg will receive "self"

Answer (score 0):

Tasnuva's answer was right.
You can try this to clean up your code.

```
class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, course, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.course = course
```

About your second case, the super() mistaken the self to street. So it did work but not very exactly.
You can try print out PrHome.street then see.

If you change your code to

```
 def __init__(self, prospect, street, number):   
     super().__init__(self, street, number)
```

it will not work (same as your 1st case)